# Strange inheritance of namedtuple methods in custom class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.6, namedtuple

My goal is to create a class that behaves like a tuple except for the equality/inequality method(s), because I *don't* want`MyTuple(1, 2, 3) == (1, 2, 3)`
to be `True` and I want to use it for dictionary keys that are distinct from its `tuple` counterparts. I finally did it, but I came across some strange behavior that is unexplainable to me.

I thought the most convenient way to reach this goal, was to inherit from a `namedtuple`. To prove a point, at first without the special (in)equality methods:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'a b c')):
   pass

print({MyTuple(1, 2, 3): 'my-tuple', (1, 2, 3): 'just-tuple'})
```

**Out:** `{MyTuple(a=1, b=2, c=3): 'just-tuple'}`

It is a bit strange that *python3.6* keeps the first key for the second value, but they are equal, so that's fine I guess.

Now I implemented the (in)equality method(s) and something unexpected happened:

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'a b c')):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, MyTuple) and tuple(self) == tuple(other)

    # No, it is not __ne__ that is missing...

print({MyTuple(1, 2, 3): 'my-tuple', (1, 2, 3): 'just-tuple'})
```

**Out:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 7 print({MyTuple(1, 2, 3): 'my-tuple', (1, 2, 3): 'just-tuple'})

TypeError: unhashable type: 'MyTuple'
```

I did not remove the `__hash__` method, so how can it disappear?

It *does* work with an additional reimplemented hash function, though:

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('MyTuple', 'a b c')):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, MyTuple) and tuple(self) == tuple(other)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self))
        # (adding some kind of salt may reduce the probability of
        # hash collsions, but it works this way)
```

**Out:**

```
{MyTuple(a=1, b=2, c=3): 'my-tuple', (1, 2, 3): 'just-tuple'}
```

**Question(s):**

- Why do I have to implement the hash method myself?
- How was it deleted in the first place?
- Is there something like an "DistinctTuple" in some Python library or some other shortcut that I have been missing?

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe. I haven't found a good target yet, though.

Comment: @user2357112 lolz, I'm sure that's useful to know :-)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing to the answer with the duplicate reference, but the second part of my question "Is there something like an `DistinctTuple` in some Python library or some other shortcut that I have been missing?" remains unanswered, doesn't it?

Comment: One question per question, please.